# cannot concatenate more than 2 strings

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I wrote a a function that has two arguments and therefore can concatenate 2 arrays of character strings. However, I need to use the same function to concatenate five arguments. That's where I am stuck, because my function does not work properly. I keeps only the last append. I pasted the code bellow. Your help will be appreciated. I wrote the code in C++, and I am using dev-C++.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>


using namespace std;


char *Append(char *str, char *add)
{
 int m=5;
 static char buffer[150];  
 char *p=buffer;
 while(*p++=*str++);
 p--;
 while(*p++=*add++);  

 return buffer;  

}

int main()
{
 static char *buffer1;
 char *temp=" "; 
 char *str="Be, ";
 char *add="or not to be, ";
 char *str3="that's the question ";
 char *str4="Whether 'tis Nobler in the mind to suffer ";
 char *str5="The Slings and Arrows of outrageous Fortune,";

 buffer1=Append(str, add);
 cout<<buffer1;
 ///while(*temp++=*buffer1++);//where the problem starts!  
 /// temp--;
 Append(temp, str);    ///i am trying to append all strings into temp!!
 buffer1=Append (temp, add);
 cout<<endl<<buffer1;


 getch();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using a static local here is really not a good idea, you should be using heap-based memory for your ongoing builds of new strings. I assume you cannot use `std::string` because of the parameters of your project? Because that is the obvious choice here.

Comment: are you talking about the one in the main or Append function?

Comment: and the reason you are not using std::string is?

Comment: They are equally inadvisable. Avoid globals unless you absolutely must have them. Since you only ever have one `main`, making a local variable static there does not add much. In general in C++ you want to avoid raw pointers and use RAII types (classes) that encapsulate them instead - in the case of C-String that type is `std::string`

Comment: Have you covered memory allocation and release yet?

Comment: @T4000: If your professor wrote that code, you need to ask the department head to arrange some additional C++ training for him.  That code is terrible.  Let me count the ways: unused variable `m`.  static variable in `main`.  Binding non-`const` `char*` to string literals.  Using `char*` in the function signature where `const char*` would be appropriate.  Not checking for buffer overflow.  Beyond these things which are clearly wrong, the whole approach is questionable.

Comment: @Ben - agreed, if this is presented as model C++ code or function design it's no wonder the class is confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're writing the concatenated string into a static buffer (`static char buffer[150];`). Every time you call the append function, you write into the same buffer, which means you overwrite the string created by the previous call to append.

```
 buffer1=Append(str, add); // buffer1 contains "Be, or not to be, "
 Append(temp, str); // buffer1 now contains " Be, " even though you don't assign the result of Append to buffer1
```

However, you can still make it work if you do:

```
buffer1=Append(str, add);
Append(buffer1, str3);
Append(buffer1, str4);
Append(buffer1, str5);
```

Though you have to be careful not to overrun your buffer.

This works because when you pass buffer1 in as the first string the append function's first step becomes copying the previously concatenated string into itself, and the second step is to add on the new string.

Comment: I see my mistake now. I tried that at one point, but because buffer1 was static, it overwrote itself and I ended up only with the last string into buffer1. Now I fixed everything, and it works fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @T4000: It has nothing to do with whether `buffer1` (your pointer in `main()`) is static.  `main()` is only called once, `static` on a primitive type has absolutely no effect.

Answer (score 1):

your question is not completely clear to me.Still,assuming that you want Append() to be used multiple times to concatenate consecutive 5 string, use main() like this.

```
int main()
 {
 static char *buffer1;
 char *temp=" "; 
 char *str="Be, ";
 char *add="or not to be, ";
 char *str3="that's the question ";
 char *str4="Whether 'tis Nobler in the mind to suffer ";
 char *str5="The Slings and Arrows of outrageous Fortune,";

 buffer1=Append(str, add);
 cout<<buffer1;
 ///while(*temp++=*buffer1++);//where the problem starts!  
 /// temp--;
 buffer1=Append(buffer1, str3);    ///i am trying to append all strings into temp!!
 buffer1=Append(buffer1,str4);
 buffer1=Append(buffer1,str5);
 cout<<endl<<buffer1;


 getch();
return 0;
}
```